# Как лучше сделать mysql запрос?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Есть три таблички: wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships (не буду скрывать - да, это wordpress). Как лучше сконструировать такой запрос: выделить все записи из wp_posts в которых категория номер 4 и опция ES>$t.
Поясню: в таблице wp_term_relationships записано ид категории и ид записи. В таблице wp_postmeta ид записи, название опции, значение опции. В общем на глупую голову я бы сделал так:

```
$t   = time();
$res = mysql_query("SELECT object_id, term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id=4");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT ID,post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE ID='$row[object_id]' and post_status='publish'");
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
    $res3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id='$row2[ID]' and meta_key='ES' and meta_value>$t");
    if (mysql_num_rows($res3) > 0)
        $POSTS[$i]['cont'] = $row2[post_content];
    $i++;
}
```

но я знаю, что можно намного лучше сделать, без большой нагрузки БД, но как хз. Пож-та, помогите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так )

```
SELECT * FROM wp_term_relationships a
LEFT JOIN  wp_posts b
ON a.object_id = b.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c
ON b.ID = c.post_id 
WHERE a.term_taxonomy_id=4 
AND b.post_status='publish'  
AND c.meta_key='ES' 
AND c.meta_value>$t
```

Comment: Спасибо. И ещё вопрос прям здесь задам. Зачем разработчики cms id категории для записи вынесли в другую таблицу? Почему нельзя было создать ещё один столбик ,например cat_id в wp_posts.

Comment: Не могу сказать с точностью, но предположу что это попытка нормальзовать базу данных.. 

В проектированиее структуры базы данных есть пункт нормализации базы данных, что представляет собой удаление связей многие ко многим путем добавления таблиц связей..

Comment: Может быть, потому что одна запись в WP может относиться к нескольким категориям?